Unrealistic standard deviation in Zonal Statistics of ArcGIS Pro
I'm using the Zonal Statistics as Table tool in ArcGIS Pro 3.2.0 to calculate the average raster values for each polygon feature (I have 4 polygons in total). While the mean values seem reasonable, the standard deviation (STD) values appear unrealistic. For example, if the mean value for a polygon is 97, the calculated STD can be something like 135, which seems impossible as the raster does not contain values less than 0.
Both the raster and the polygon feature layer use the same coordinate system: Projected Coordinate System: EUREF_FIN_TM35FIN.
Could these inflated or unrealistic standard deviation values be related to the coordinate system, resolution mismatch, or something else in the zonal statistics process?


Have you read the help file and how the tool computes the values? It explains exactly how STD is computed.

Your MAX values confirm that std values are realistic.
